# Polysemous & ambigous terms

Tags: discussion

I've been working on maintaining a ["Vocabulary for Scientific Data Systems"](http://virtualsolar.org/vocab) for a few years (one of these days I'll have enough free time to clean it up and publish, but I want to get it in SKOS w/ crosswalks to some of the other discipline-specific glossaries).

Would it be appropriate to in some way put that sort of information this site?  Maybe something similar to Cooking.SE's [Translating cooking terms between US / UK / AU / CA / NZ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67), to flag prolematic terms between disciplines?

** Disclaimer : yes, I'm the one who started / maintains that question on Cooking.SE .

**update:** fixed link (pasted w/out the 'http://' in it)

**update 2:** From the intro / abstract for the vocabulary :

> Virtual Observatories and other unifying data systems have been forming in nearly every science discipline. As is common in any field, language evolves to discuss the concepts, but it may evolve differently when communities don’t intercommunicate. In order to discuss our organizations and data systems across disciplines, we must have a clear language to be able to communicate information about our systems and the content within our systems. We present common terms and definitions used in earth and space informatics when discussing science archives, search systems, services and other data system components. One benefit of a common vocabulary is to help those who implement science data systems to easily recognize other efforts with a common purpose. A common vocabulary is also useful in identifying analogous terms in other fields such as computer science and information science.

I would assume the focus on here would be on content of the systems, but we might need the other bits for context.

Comment: related : http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7/263

Comment: Your cooking term translation post seems very helpful! However, I still can't think of an example where a translation list like this would be helpful on Open Data SE. Do you have a concrete use case in mind?

Comment: @PatrickHoefler : (1) building a list by field/discipline of where 'dataset' means 'granule' vs. 'collection'.  (2) Similar to the cooking one, tracking & defining jargon that may be used in only a few disciplines, and defining what they mean (and what disciplines they're doing in, and how it might vary ) (3) Documenting that 'sample' is polysemous -- for telescope data, it's a process of selective reduction (one image an hour, every 4th image) ... for hydrology, it's the process of actually collecting water to be analyzed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @PatrickHoefler : so for #2, it'd be a place to document every time we have to ask someone to clarify what they mean when they use a term that someone else doesn't understand.  For #3, it's for those times when we *didn't* ask for clarification, and instead misunderstood what they were asking for.  I thought I was pretty clear in my question where I mentioned [ASCII tables](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/259/263), but maybe it means something different to other people (or they mis-read 'table' as 'text' or 'file')